# OPENCV How can I read and use Bayer filter on a NEF image?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, rawimage

I'm currently using opencv C++ to process images that have file type NEF. But imread doesn't seem to work on raw images. Does anyone know how to read and use Bayer filter on a NEF type image?  Thanks!
http://www.mannyphoto.com/D700D3/ 
here are some sample pictures.

Comment: Please, [edit] your post and attach a link to a sample NEF image.

Comment: I can't use personal images but I did find images online.http://www.mannyphoto.com/D700D3/ @DanMašek

Comment: It took me 10 seconds on google to find out that you cannot read raw files with OpenCV. But of course you can write your own code or use libraries like LibRaw (which took me another 10 seconds to find)... come on

Comment: Try `ufraw`... http://ufraw.sourceforge.net